# I thought vs. I thought that

Tags: word-usage

I'm composing a rather important letter and I am stuck and struggling on how to pose this question:
I thought women were necessary to the...  ~vs~
I thought that women were necessary to the....

Comment: Identical meanings. The first omits the subordinator "that" which is permitted in most constructions like this. Normally, "that" is used in formal settings.

Comment: And I apologize for asking a duplicate question.  I had just joined and read the rules carefully.  I know this is frowned upon.  I put forth my best efforts in searching the site for an answer, prior to posing the question. I didn't have any luck, and now I'm not sure why.  I'll try to be more diligent next time.